# Does the following graph have a Hamilton circuit?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

[image]

A Hamilton circuit (or path) is a path that visits each vertex exactly once (except the start/end point) and ends at the starting point.

I've stared at this for quite a while and cannot find a Hamilton circuit yet my guide says that one exists. Where is the path?

Comment: 11,12,13,10,8,5,3,2,1,4,7,9,6,11

Comment: Wow, how did you do that so fast? Is there a particular method that is useful for finding the Hamilton circuit?

Comment: 1, 4, 7, 9, 6, 11, 12, 10, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1.

Comment: It is interesting that all 3 found the same circuit, though another exists by symmetry - $1,2,3,8,5,7,10,13, 12, 11,9,6,4$.

Comment: If you do even go randomly in this graph, you find the hamiltinian path with a big probability, seriously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the lexicographically first Hamilton cycle (found using a backtracking algorithm):

[image: A Hamilton cycle]

Comment: Nice! Off topic but I hate using MS paint for diagrams, what did you use for this?

Comment: Tikz; I give an explanation on meta.maths.SE [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9444/139).

Answer (score 1):

$1,2,5,3,8,10,13,12,11,6,9,7,4,1$

Comment: Is there a particular method you are using or recommend for finding the Hamilton circuit?

Comment: @Kevin: No, I just tinkered a bit. I started with $1,4,2,5,3,8$ but quickly realized that the $4$ killed off any chance to use the $7$, so I deleted it and considered $1,2,5,3,8$; the rest pretty much wrote itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion on Hamilton cycle problem and associated algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107545/how-to-find-hamiltonian-cycle-in-a-graph). Also, please take a look at the [PairViz](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PairViz/PairViz.pdf) package of R.